# Integrate teltonika gps tracker with Thingsboard platform

Tags: gps, tracking, thingsboard, teltonika

I am wondering if anyone tried or has a clue how to integrate teltonika gps tracker device with Thingsboard IoT platform. So, to get gps data from a tracker device, parse it and store it on platform like any other IoT device. Teltonika has its own communication protocol so I don't know if the integration is possible and how

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a broker in between your GPS device and ThingsBoard, I have used Gurtam Flespi platform before and it worked.